# How to cache a dictionary value at the startup of a process

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a custom application(service) and a CLI which I start as follows `mycli system start`. This starts the cli. And then I can run other CLI commands. I want to cache some values at the startup so that they don't get calculated again and again.

I saw there are some ways to do this in python 2.7 but I couldn't find a way to retain the cached value after the startup script has completed. For eg:
https://dbader.org/blog/python-memoization This blog talks about caching values but this caches every time I run the script. Basically it caches the values for the first time every time I run the script. Once the script has completed the values are lost. What is the best way to cache values in such case in Python 2.7? Because in my case I want the value to be retained even after the startup script has completed for the subsequent CLI operations.

Comment: Have the script create and maintain a config file.

Comment: the values I want to retain are credentials so dont want to have them in clear text.